# Why doesn't the Legend title change?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a melted dataframe. It's name "melted_data".

```
     Tr   variable  value
1  3.00        J48 0.3500
2  3.25        J48 0.6300
3  3.50        J48 0.4820
4  3.75        J48 0.4210
5  4.00        J48 0.6357
6  4.25        J48 0.8412
7  3.00     ADTree 0.4215
8  3.25     ADTree 0.1856
9  3.50     ADTree 0.6260
10 3.75     ADTree 0.7825
11 4.00     ADTree 0.8425
12 4.25     ADTree 0.3085
13 3.00    LADTree 0.2365
14 3.25    LADTree 0.6480
15 3.50    LADTree 0.7560
16 3.75    LADTree 0.8467
17 4.00    LADTree 0.7891
18 4.25    LADTree 0.3678
19 3.00 RandomTree 0.7400
20 3.25 RandomTree 0.3840
21 3.50 RandomTree 0.8421
22 3.75 RandomTree 0.2356
23 4.00 RandomTree 0.6378
24 4.25 RandomTree 0.4717
25 3.00    RepTree 0.1260
26 3.25    RepTree 0.3720
27 3.50    RepTree 0.9274
28 3.75    RepTree 0.6842
29 4.00    RepTree 0.2536
30 4.25    RepTree 0.3654
```

There are a lot of questions on this subject. However, none of the answers worked for me. It didn't work to add "`+ labs (color =" NEW LEGEND TITLE ")`" or "`+scale_fill_discrete (name =" New Legend Title ")`" to the end. When I add these codes, there are two legends.

I want the legend title to write "Algorithms" instead of "variable".

[image: plot_zoom]

The codes that make up this plot are listed below.

```
ggplot(data=melted_data,aes(x=`Tr`,y=`value`))+
geom_line(aes(linetype=variable),size=0.65)+
geom_point(aes(shape=variable),size=1.75)+
xlab("Tr")+ylab("Id Average")+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=0, hjust=0.7))+ 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(3, 4.25, 0.25))+
geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(melted_data$variable=="RandomTree",melted_data$value,NA)),vjust=-0.2)+
theme(legend.position = c(0.85,0.2))+
theme(legend.background = element_rect(colour = 'grey', fill = 'white', linetype='solid'))
```

Comment: . Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls.

Comment: Try labs(linetype = "Algorithms", color = "Algorithms"). You have two aes and two legends. Legends get onyl merged if they have the same name.

Comment: As @stefan says, but they only get merged when the limits, breaks and labels are the same too (as well as the name); I think.

Comment: @sindri_baldur thank you. I tried to provide the necessary information and updated it.

Comment: @stefan thank you. I added the table to the question. I am waiting for your comments.

Comment: @teunbrand thank you. Could there be more than one aes? Would this be unnecessary? What is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was enough to change the name of the column.

```
colnames(melted_data)[2] = "Algorithms"
```

It's somewhat dramatic that the only way to modify it is to change the column name.